# How to generate chromium android build?

Tags: chromium, chromium-os

I have created a new repository and pushed the chromium using .gitignore to avoid unwanted libraries while generating build. Then again i cloned and try to build using the mentioned steps I am getting error. Please help me to fix this

Since I made code changes I cant get fresh checkout from google

Step 1:git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git -**DONE**

Step 2: example export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/depot_tools" - **DONE**

Step 3: fetch --nohooks android - **DONE**

Step 4: gclient sync **DONE**

Step 5: build/install-build-deps-android.sh **DONE**

Step 6: gclient runhooks

Step 7 : gn args out/Default **FAILED** below error

```
ERROR Can't find source root.
I could not find a ".gn" file in the current directory or any parent,
and the --root command-line argument was not specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is running on Linux? Windows and Mac are not supported.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."